# Troubles with apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, udev

I am having troubles with apt-get upgrade, ever since I removed and purged the udev program.

Here's the error I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done 0 upgraded, 0
newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed
or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be
used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu17)
... addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group.
Exiting. update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides

insserv: There is a loop between service torque-scheduler and
vncserver if stopped 
insserv:  loop involving service vncserver at depth 2 
insserv:  loop involving service torque-scheduler at depth 1
insserv: Stopping vncserver depends on torque-scheduler and therefore
on system facility `$all' which can not be true! 
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order! 
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header 
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
status 1 
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.5) ... 
insserv: warning: script 'vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides 
insserv: There is a loop between service torque-scheduler and vncserver if stopped 
insserv:  loop involving service vncserver at depth 2 
insserv: loop involving service torque-scheduler at depth 1 insserv: Stopping
vncserver depends on torque-scheduler and therefore on system facility
`$all' which can not be true! insserv: exiting now without changing

 boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
status 1 
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic 
Errors were encountered while processing:  udev  unattended-upgrades 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Excuse me, you did what, why on earth did you do that?

Comment: I was having probles with TorqueServer and I saw here on StackExchange that I should remove a few packages one of them being udev to make it work. Sorry I'm really new at all this that's why I am asking for help! Thank you

Comment: See if you can re-install it from [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/udev) use the `64bit .deb` option. Double click to launch. ASK IF NOT SURE!

Comment: Seems like your problem is caused by vncserver, not udev.